# How to choose which JDBC driver to use?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, h2

I have included the MySQL connector dependency and h2database dependency to my project. I then try to get an H2 JDBC connection, but an exception is thrown instead from what looks like the MySQL JDBC connector.

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test", "sa", "");
```

The exception thrown is along the lines of:

```
com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Connector/J cannot handle a database URL of type 'jdbc:h2:'.
```

How do I access both an H2 database, and a MySQL database?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Did you do anything special to get them registered?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a know bug and have been verified but there is not solution provide for it yet other than the work around in my answer.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this bug using mysql 5.7.15 and the latest version of connector/j (6.0.4). Could you please share enough java code and the exact setup you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a reported bug:

[Bug #82896](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82896)

> [7 Sep 21:33] Artem Lodygin Description: Attempt to connect to mySql
>   JDBC driver with unsupported URL causes WrongArgumentException
>   stacktrace to be printed to console, such as:
>
> com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Connector/J
>   cannot handle a database URL of type 'jdbc:h2:mem:test' **stacktrace
>   follows**
>
> When several JDBC drivers are registered in the system, it happens on
>   every connection attempt to all drivers chained below mysql.
>
> Expected behavior is SILENTLY failing with SQLException.
>
> How to repeat: Put mysql connector jar into classpath. Do NOT put
>   com.h2database driver into classpath. Execute the following code:
>
> DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test", null, null);
>
> Suggested fix: Remove "e.printStackTrace();" from the method 
>   ConnectionUrl getConnectionUrlInstance(String connString, Properties
>   info)

Comment: and the only answer is to remove H2? why not removing mysql instead? I'm sure a workaround is possible, as in my ETL cases I'm able to handle both jdbc connections. I'll look into this, but to me this answer (remove h2 only) is not acceptable as a fix, if indeed the user needs h2 connection

Comment: @ChristianMICHON That isn't the answer, it is the reproduction step to make sure that the H2 driver isn't registered first, which could cause the reported problem to not occur.

Comment: I just chose to use the 5.1.39 connector and the output stopped happening.